# How to configure PySpark job based on Parquet input?

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, apache-spark, amazon-emr

**What I have**

2 datasets on HDFS in Parquet format:

- 1.6T (after parquet uncompressing it's going to be 2.8T), 31 columns, I assume there is no data skew and all data distributed across HDFS evenly
- 200G (after parquet uncompressing it will be 360G), 5 columns, no data skew and data distributed evenly

I use AWS EMR cluster to run PySpark job.

**What I need to do**

Since experimenting isn't cheap, I want to calculate PySpark job configuration based on the input configuration and my assumptions before I even run it on the cluster.

Here are some details. I need to join datasets by one *id* column to enrich first dataset (1.6T) with data (only 3 columns: *string, string, struct<int, string, string>*) from the second dataset (200G).

**Question**

How can I decide what are the number of *executors*, *cpu cores*, *memory*, and *[disk?]* I need to request for my PySpark job?

(And is there any general formula for that?)